# User Script. Перехват события на сайте без дальнейшей обработки события этим сайтом

Tags: html

Хочу написать скрипт. Пользователь нажимает мышкой на окно сайта, мой скрипт перехватывает это событие, обрабатывает его, но вот сам сайт его уже не обрабатывает. Например пользователь нажал на ссылку на сайте, мой скрипт среагировал, а сайт никак не реагирует( то есть никуда не перенаправляет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `onclick="return false;"` как атрибут в `<body>`

```html
<html>
<body onclick="return false;">
  <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
    <h3>Stackoverflow</h3><br></a>
  <form>
    <button type='sumbit'>Sumbit</button>
  </form>
</body>
<html>
```